# How to use an existing .qcow2 to create another VM with virhsh/qemu?

Tags: command-line, virtualization, qemu, kvm, virsh

I have a Red Hat 6.9 .qcow2 with working system and I would like to clone/replicate it to another VM (or as domain how virsh calls it) but when I use the following command:

```
virt-install  \
--name rhel69  \
--ram 4096  \
--disk path=./rhel69_vol.qcow2,size=32  \
--vcpus 4  \
--os-type linux  \
--os-variant generic  \
--boot hd  \
--network bridge=virbr1,mac=52:54:00:12:34:56  \
--graphics none  \
--console pty,target_type=serial
```

I have my VM created but I cannot access the console like so:

```
virsh console rhel69
```

and the VM's process on the host takes 100% CPU. I have enough RAM to host it. I tried e.g. `virsh console rhel69` but I get nothing.

What am I doing wrong?